# Which version of mermaid is supported in Azure DevOps Wikis

Tags: azure-devops, mermaid

Which version of mermaid is currently supported in AzureDevOps? In the official docs it only mentions some diagrams that are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the files downloaded from the Developer Tools: Network tab.  I first thought it was 6.3 based upon the url but looking into the json I saw this...

```
"./package.json":function(e){e.exports={name:"mermaid",version:"8.2.3",description:"Markdownish syntax for generating flowcharts, sequence diagrams, class diagrams, gantt charts and git graphs.",main:"dist/mermaid.core.js",keywords:["diagram","markdown","flowchart","sequence diagram","gantt","class diagram","git graph"]
```

So as of this moment... I believe it to be 8.2.3

Answer (score 7):

As of [Sprint 200](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-200-update#support-for-additional-diagram-types-in-wiki-pages) (March 2022) the following diagrams are supported up to version 8.13.9:

- Flowchart
- Sequence diagrams
- Gantt charts
- Pie charts
- Requirement diagrams
- State diagrams
- User Journey

Comment: Huh, the release clearly states that those are supported. However, as soon as I change my chart type to Flowchart, rendering breaks, and a message is displayed instead: "Unsupported diagram type".

Comment: @BrunoBrant On [their documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#flowchart-example) they say: _We don't support `---->` or `flowchart` syntax, nor links to and from `subgraph`._ The substitute that seems to work as of today is `graph`.

Comment: @Mattew Steeples Trouble is, their documentation does not match the actual functionality - pie charts, state diagrams, and user journeys still do not render. I have asked the team about it. They were responsive at first, but now have ghost the inquiry for a date. The "in a few weeks" statement in the release notes is clearly inaccurate.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description, I further checked this problem. Currently, the wiki [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#add-mermaid-diagrams-to-a-wiki-page) the following Mermaid diagram types:

1. [Sequence diagrams](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/sequenceDiagram)
2. [Gantt Charts](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/gantt)

Wiki does not support other types of Mermaid diagrams, so this seems to have nothing to do with the version. Regarding this feature, I help you find a [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/883356/mermaid-support-for-class-diagrams-and-state-diagr.html). You can vote and add comments on it.

Comment: This information is not helpful since it does not describe which features in the sequence diagrams are supported. And actually flow charts are also supported but it is not clear what is supported as part of "Flow charts" supports. If the exact version would be known we could check in the release notes of mermaid itself for the supported features.

Comment: I tested this problem further, this seems to have nothing to do with the version. As long as it belongs to the Mermaid diagram types supported by the official document, then their features are supported.

Comment: Ok. That means since I was not using an officially supported diagram type (Flowchart) you cannot give any details?
Can't you please forward this question to dev? They can answer this question in a matter of 5 mins and then I am also happy since I get the answer that I am seeking.

Comment: If you havent already, you should post this as an issue/question on the Mermaid github repo: https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues.

However, keep in mind that they will not be able to answer the question of which version is being used, since that is controlled by Azure.

Comment: As an interesting side bit - while the page that @AlinaWang-MSFT points to does say only Sequence Diagrams and Gantt Charts are supported, the screenshot shows a Flowchart diagram ;)

Comment: Another addition to this issue, mermaid support is only available on the cloud version of Azure DevOps currently, not on the on-premise version.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can actually use any type of diagram in Azure DevOps using embedded markdown links. From the [mermaid live editor](https://mermaid.live/), expand the "Actions" section and click on "COPY MARKDOWN" button:

[image]

output:
[image]

This relies on the mermaid.ink webservice so it's not entirely reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I fear I am not allowed to save/transfer company ip diagrams on some public mermaid server.

Comment: This is gold! But I am afraid it will be cumbersome to maintain the updates in future for complex diagrams.

Comment: I was wrong when I tried it actually as long as `mermaid.ink` service is working. Add your diagram to Wiki as markdown. In future just tap on the diagram and it will open the mermaid editor for you! Voila!

Answer (score 2):

Sad that azure devops (server) wiki still not support mermaid.

One hack could be using the 'markdown' button on https://mermaid.live/
and then paste the markdown from mermaid.live into devops wiki.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE
From this [release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/wiki/sprint-200-update), all the diagram types in the following list are supported:

- Sequence diagrams
- Gantt charts
- Flowcharts
- Pie charts
- Requirement diagrams
- State diagrams
- User Journey

--- Original Post ---

Checking the listed [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#add-mermaid-diagrams-to-a-wiki-page) page it shows the following diagrams as supported:

Supported:

- Sequence diagrams
- Gantt charts
- Flowcharts

Unsupported:

- Pie charts
- Requirement diagrams
- State diagrams
- User Journey

Testing each of the diagram types in a DevOps wiki page using the examples from the mermaid website, the first three work. The rest return an error "Unsupported diagram type". Truly amazing they have it documented as supported but in reality its not.

Comment: I have tried personally and discovered that, all except ER and Mermaid are supported!

Comment: This is due to a recent release that enabled more of the diagram types.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/wiki/sprint-200-update

Comment: This answer needs update hence!

Answer (score 0):

erDiagram & stateDiagram-v2 are not working on dev.azure on 20231229
works fine in visual studio code with Markdown Editor v2